# Bull-Board - incomplete interface presentation - missing CSS?

Tags: node.js, npm

Bull-Board UI is working. But the display presentation - seems to be wrong. Appears to be some CSS missing eventually?
Package GIThub Link:
https://github.com/vcapretz/bull-board

The Way i see it:
[image]

The way it's meant to be (Example from the development site):

[image]

I'm Running Node.js on a Windows machine

Answer (score 0):

From the Developer's Git Page:

This was the old design, it changed in the v1.10-alpha, you can install it from npm using

npm install bull-board@1.0.0-alpha.12
Or using git clone git@github.com:vcapretz/bull-board.git

- thats the solution -